# Table View Cell size changing

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, tableview, pftableviewcell

I have been having an issue with my TableView in Xcode using Swift.

I am using Parse, (Sad its shutting down soon) but I think the problem is in the Interface Builder. (IB) The issue is that it adds a huge white space below each cell.

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8iRJ.png) a link to the picture: (I don't have enough reputation to post images straight in the question)

As you can see in the cell on the IB, there is no space but for some reason it adds this huge space. I have checked the image resolution and size and its the exact size for the UIImageView

Comment: What are you setting for the row height? Are you implementing  tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:? Or estimatedRowHeight?

Comment: I haven't set anything in the code. All I have set is the values in the IB.

Comment: And what is it set to? You should set constraints for the views in your tableviewcell then set tableView.estimatedRowHeight

Comment: Oh. That seemed to fix it. The TableView cell size was different from the cell's custom size.

Comment: @beyowulf If you could publish an official answer I can verify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup constraints in your UITableViewCell. Then in viewDidLoad say something like:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 120.0 //Or some other approximation of your cell's height
```

This will cause your table view's cells' height to be determined by the constraints set in the cell.